# Android viewpager, how to update fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am attempting to implement a `ViewPager` for the first time, I was able to get it to work however what I need it to be able to do is update elements within the individual fragments from time to time, I attempted to create a method inside the fragment class to do this but however it is returning a null pointer at the moment, can anyone who has done this before give me a few tips as to how to make this work? any help will go a long way thanks!

here is my fragment activity and adapter:

```
public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);

    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();

    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    MyFragment theFragment = (MyFragment) fragments.get(0);
    theFragment.receiveUpdate();
  }

private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
    fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 2"));
    fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 3"));

    return fList;
}

class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {

        super(fm);

        this.fragments = fragments;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return this.fragments.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return this.fragments.size();

    }

}

}
```

and here is my actual fragment class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";
TextView messageTextView;

public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message) {
    MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
    bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}

public void receiveUpdate() {
    // Do something
    messageTextView.setText("changed");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);

    messageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    messageTextView.setText(message);

    ListView fragList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] from = new String[] { "str", "str", "str", "str", "str",
            "str", "str", "str", "str" };

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(v.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from);

    fragList.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}

}
```

Comment: do you want to replace fragments in the pager or pass a message to the fragment to update something within the fragment?

Comment: Id like to update the messageTextView to a different string dynamically, I tried doing the update in the oncreate to see if it will work but it just returned a nullpointer

Comment: what line do you get the exception on

Comment: Line 32, basically when I call recieveUpdate in the OnCreate